# What are "CSS Regions" and why should I care about them?

Tags: css

I just read an article that mentions CSS Regions, so Goggled to find out what they are.   I was expecting that a **short**, independent explanation of them would show up at the top of the results, it did not.

Hence asking this question, so that the next time someone does the same Google, there will be a good answer waiting for them at the top of the results.

Comment: This isn't short, but it's shorter than reading the whole specification: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/css3-regions.html

Comment: [This critique](http://alistapart.com/blog/post/css-regions-considered-harmful) is also worth reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to be short, Regions are a way to layout the site's textual content in a more complex manner. For example:

[image: Example headline + 3 columns]
[Image Source](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/css3-regions.html)

This is created with the following markup (omitted unnecessary styling):

```
<h1>Flowing Text</h1>
<div id="text_source">When the beginning of your article... (continues) ...Flows allow this kind of flexibility.</div>
<div class="small_text"></div>
<div class="column"></div>
<div class="column"></div>
<div class="column"></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#text_source { flow-into: text-thread; flow-from: text-thread; }
.small_text { flow-from: text-thread; }
.column { flow-from: text-thread; }
```

Behind the scenes, when an element has a `flow-into` CSS property, it's textual contents are removed from rendering and deferred to this abstract "thread" of text, that will be split across all elements that have a `flow-from` property with the same value, in the order they are found in the HTML.

Comment: This accepted answer fails to answer the most important part of the question, which is "why should I care about them?".

Comment: @torazaburo If the question was "why should I care [...]" I would vote to close as "too broad" or "opinion based". You should care if your client/employer cares, for short.

Comment: Well, that **was** the question (or the second half of it, anyway). I don't know if you can close a question with two parts when the first part has an answer and the second is a matter of opinion. Anyway, you are right about "if your client/employee cares", by definition, but I'm having a hard time imagining that clients or employees care about a feature with such narrow support.

Answer (score 3):

> I just read an article that mentions CSS Regions, so Googled to find out what they are. I was expecting that a short, independent explanation of them would show up at the top of the results

Huh? If you Google for "Ford", you get Ford's website, not a short, independent explanation about Ford.

> Why should I care about them?

You shouldn't. Currently, it's [implemented only in later IE/Edge and Safari](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-regions). It was implemented but then [removed from Chrome, due to the complexity and mobile issues](http://www.cnet.com/news/reversing-course-google-rejects-adobe-web-publishing-tech/). The chances that it will ever gain enough browser support to actually be used widely are vanishingly small.

Regions are Adobe's attempt to support magazine-like layouts on the web. However, we don't need magazine-like layouts ("continued on p. 29") on the web.